# Function for specific data frame

Tags: r

I have below mentioned data frame in R.

```
ACCOUNT_ID LOAN_AMOUNT DISBURSEMENT_DATE   LOAN_DUE_DATE   LOAN_INSTALLMENT
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/02/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/03/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/04/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/05/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/06/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/07/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/08/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/09/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/10/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/11/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/12/2018 00:00         9433
ID123       100000      08/01/2018 00:00    08/01/2019 00:00         9433
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/02/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/03/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/04/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/05/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/06/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/07/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/08/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/09/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/10/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/11/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/12/2018 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/01/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/02/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/03/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/04/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/05/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/06/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/07/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/08/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/09/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/10/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/11/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/12/2019 00:00         11533
ID456       200000      10/01/2018 00:00    10/01/2020 00:00         11533
```

For which i have function which to calculate IRR:

```
irrcalc <- function(cashflow, dates){
irr <- xirr(cashflow, dates)
return(irr)
}
```

But to use that function i want my date fame in below mentioned structure:

```
cashflow <-c(-100000,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433)
dates <- as.Date(c("08/01/2018","08/02/2018","08/03/2018","08/04/2018","08/05/2018","08/06/2018","08/07/2018","08/08/2018","08/09/2018","08/10/2018","08/11/2018","08/12/2018","08/01/2019"))
irr <- xirr(cashflow, dates)
```

For that i have a code but it takes first value correct in "cashflow" which should be -100000 but rest of the 24 vales capturing from other Account_ID(ID456) and return cashflow<- c(-100000,11533,11533,..) instead of cashflow<-c(-100000,9433,9433,...)

Please check below code:

```
NEWDATAFRAME <- data.frame(row.names = NULL)
nrow <- 1
for (acct in unique(DFNAME[,"ACCOUNT_ID"])){

  cashflow <- DFNAME[DFNAME[,"ACCOUNT_ID"] == acct,"LOAN_INSTALLMENT"]
  cashflow[1] <- -DFNAME[1,"LOAN_AMOUNT"]

  dates <- DFNAME[DFNAME[,"ACCOUNT_ID"] == acct,"LOAN_DUE_DATE"]
  dates[1] <- DFNAME[1,"DISBURSEMENT_DATE"]

  NEWDATAFRAME[nrow,"ACCOUNT_ID"] <- acct
  NEWDATAFRAME[nrow,"IRR"]  <- irrcalc(cashflow,dates)

  nrow <- nrow + 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the function `xirr()`, however if my understanding is correct the code below should put the data in the format you need.

I have imported your data into the data.frame `d`, and converted dates into date format (using `as.Date(d$DISBURSEMENT_DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")`). This is what I have:

```
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ ACCOUNT_ID       : Factor w/ 2 levels "ID123","ID456": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LOAN_AMOUNT      : int  100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 100000 ...
 $ DISBURSEMENT_DATE: Date, format: "2018-01-08" "2018-01-08" "2018-01-08" ...
 $ LOAN_DUE_DATE    : Date, format: "2018-02-08" "2018-03-08" "2018-04-08" ...
 $ LOAN_INSTALLMENT : int  9433 9433 9433 9433 9433 9433 9433 9433 9433 9433 ...
```

This is the code

```
NEWDATAFRAME <- {}
for(i in unique(d$ACCOUNT_ID)){
    sub_d <- d[d$ACCOUNT_ID == i,]
    cashflow <- c(-sub_d$LOAN_AMOUNT[1], sub_d$LOAN_INSTALLMENT)
    dates <- c(sub_d$DISBURSEMENT_DATE[1], sub_d$LOAN_DUE_DATE)

    # xirr(cashflow, dates) can be added within the data.frame() call below
    NEWDATAFRAME <- rbind(NEWDATAFRAME, data.frame(cashflow, dates, id = i))
}
```

And this is the output

```
> NEWDATAFRAME
   cashflow      dates    id
1   -100000 2018-01-08 ID123
2      9433 2018-02-08 ID123
3      9433 2018-03-08 ID123
4      9433 2018-04-08 ID123
5      9433 2018-05-08 ID123
6      9433 2018-06-08 ID123
7      9433 2018-07-08 ID123
8      9433 2018-08-08 ID123
9      9433 2018-09-08 ID123
10     9433 2018-10-08 ID123
11     9433 2018-11-08 ID123
12     9433 2018-12-08 ID123
13     9433 2019-01-08 ID123
14  -200000 2018-01-10 ID456
15    11533 2018-02-10 ID456
16    11533 2018-03-10 ID456
17    11533 2018-04-10 ID456
18    11533 2018-05-10 ID456
19    11533 2018-06-10 ID456
20    11533 2018-07-10 ID456
21    11533 2018-08-10 ID456
22    11533 2018-09-10 ID456
23    11533 2018-10-10 ID456
24    11533 2018-11-10 ID456
25    11533 2018-12-10 ID456
26    11533 2019-01-10 ID456
27    11533 2019-02-10 ID456
28    11533 2019-03-10 ID456
29    11533 2019-04-10 ID456
30    11533 2019-05-10 ID456
31    11533 2019-06-10 ID456
32    11533 2019-07-10 ID456
33    11533 2019-08-10 ID456
34    11533 2019-09-10 ID456
35    11533 2019-10-10 ID456
36    11533 2019-11-10 ID456
37    11533 2019-12-10 ID456
38    11533 2020-01-10 ID456
```

Comment: Thnaks Matteo, I want this data in below mentioned function:

<code> irrcalc <- function(cashflow, dates){
irr <- xirr(cashflow, dates)
return(irr)
} </code>

Comment: Like this:----->>>cashflow <-c(-100000,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433,9433)
dates <- as.Date(c("08/01/2018","08/02/2018","08/03/2018","08/04/2018","08/05/2018","08/06/2018","08/07/2018","08/08/2018","08/09/2018","08/10/2018","08/11/2018","08/12/2018","08/01/2019"))
irr <- xirr(cashflow, dates)

Comment: which created new data frame with only two cloumn (1) ID (2) IRR

Comment: then you just need to change the last line of the loop into something like `rbind(NEWDATAFRAME, data.frame(ID = i, IRR=xirr(cashflow, dates)))`

Comment: Hi Matteo, I'm getting IRR negative for some id that is because there would be some mismatch in cashflow and date. Tried to diagnose the issue but couldn't get it... Would you please check and see where is the problem with the code.

Comment: The code above put the data in the format you requested; if the rest of the dataset is consistent with the sample you provided, then there should be no problems. Perhaps there are some missing lines in the dataset?

Comment: Thanks Matteo, It's working fine, there was some issue with my code.